# Using "is null" when retrieving prices doesn't work

Tags: ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to get the price items for performance block storage that are generic (not specific to a certain datacenter). I can see that these have the locationGroupId set to blank or null, but I can't seem to get the objectFilter to work with that, the query returns nothing. If I omit the locationGroupId filter I get a result that contain both location-specific and non-location specific prices.

`GET /rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices.json?objectMask=mask[locationGroupId,id,categories,item]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"performance_storage_space"}},"item":{"keyName":{"operation":"$=GBs"}},"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}`

I am guessing there is something wrong with the object filter, any ideas?

If I filter on locationGroupId 509 it works:

`/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices.json?objectMask=mask[locationGroupId,id,categories,item]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"performance_storage_space"}},"item":{"keyName":{"operation":"$=GBs"}},"locationGroupId":{"operation":509}}}`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it the first query didn't work while the second did was that I used the command "curl -sg" to do the request. While that eliminates the need to escape the {}[] characters - it also turns off escaping other characters correctly in the URL - like the space in "is null". Changing that to "is%20null" solves the issue.

I am posting this as the answer as I find it likely for others to encounter this problem.